# call() Vs bind() in java script ; why bind() is introduced even in the presence of call ()

Tags: javascript

In one of the blogs I've learnt that `.bind()` will just hard bind the passed object to 'this' where as `.call()` will execute that function in addition. However, assigning the `.call()` to other variable will achieve the same purpose. I'm trying to understand why `.bind()` is introduced or am i missing something?
Following is the code that proves what i'm saying above:

```
function foo () {
    console.log( this.a );
}

let obj = {
    a: 2,
    foo: foo
};

let a = 'oops! global';

let foocall = foo.call (obj);
let foobind = foo.bind (obj);

foo.call (obj);

setTimeout ( foocall , 100);
setTimeout ( foo , 100);
```

**output:**

> [xyz: ~/sandboxes/js]$ node --use-strict binding.js 2 2 2

Comment: The output of your quoted code is **not** what you've shown (e.g., not `2` shown three times).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, assigning the .call() to other variable will achieve the same purpose.

No. I don't know where you've read that, but it's completely wrong. Assigning the result of `call` assigns the result of calling the function. It does not do what `bind` does.

In your code, `foocall` is `undefined`. Why? Because you've **called** `foo` and assigned its return value to `foocall`. Since `foo` never uses `return` with a value, the result of calling `foo` is `undefined`.

[`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) **calls** the function (the clue is in the name :-) ), setting the value `this` will have during the call.

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) does **not** call the function, it returns a new function that, when called, will call the original with `this` set to a specific value (and optionally with initial arguments, if you supply those in addition to the `this` value when calling `bind`).

Those links are to MDN (I used to link to the spec, back when the spec was intelligible to normal people), which has further explanations and examples. (Thank you for the reminder, [Oskar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2653611/oskar)!)

Here's a corrected example:

```js
function foo(label) {
  snippet.log(label + ", " + this.a);
}

var obj = {
  a: 2,
  foo: foo
};

var a = 'oops! global';

// CALLS `foo`, setting `this` during the call to `obj`.
// Result: Outputs "call1, 2" to the console.
var foocall = foo.call(obj, "call1");

// Since `foo` doesn't return anything, `foocall` is `undefined`
snippet.log("foocall's value: " + foocall);

// Calls `foo`, just like we did earlier
// Result: Outputs "call2, 2" to the console.
foo.call(obj, "call2");

// DOES NOT call `foo`. Just creates a new function that,
// when called, will call `foo` with `this` set to `obj`.
var foobind = foo.bind(obj, "bound");

// Calls the bound version of `foo` after 100ms
// Result: "bound, 2" 100ms later
setTimeout(foobind, 100);

// Calls `foo` after 100ms. Since we're in loose mode,
// `foo` will get called with `this` set to the global object.
// Result: "undefined, oops! global" because we haven't passed
// a value for the `label` argument, and `this` is the global object
setTimeout(foo, 100);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That was very clear.
Well, you may need to edit line number 20, replace call1 with call2. It's a typo during copy/paste.